# Bold upright lowercase greek symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold, greek

[image]

In a physics textbook I met an equation, as in Figure above, with the bold upright greek letter `β`.

How could I edit equations that contain such  characters in boldface?

Comment: Those are Lorentz transformation equations for non-standard orientation of the frame of references, I assume?

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer : Yes, exactly !

Comment: I would  define a command `\vec` that would check if its argument is certain letters and output conveniently what you want them to look, so `\vec a \vec \beta \vec x` would be converted  to `\mathbf{a} \bm{\upbeta} \mathbf{x}`, for instance.

Comment: @Manuel : please read my first comment in Christian Hupfer's answer to see where I'm interesting  to use it for.

Comment: That's off topic here, and personally I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: @Manuel : Yes, I realize that it's off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is interested in a Mathjax-only solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `upgreek` package and `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` (or `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 x'_{0} &= \gamma \left( x_{0} - \boldsymbol{\upbeta \cdot x}\right) \\
 \boldsymbol{x}' &= \boldsymbol{x} + \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\boldsymbol{\upbeta}^2}  \left( \boldsymbol{\upbeta \cdot x}\right)\boldsymbol{\upbeta} - \gamma \boldsymbol{\upbeta} x_{0} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I edit upgreek in bold in an equation written inside an answer or a question in Physics SE, for example therein : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254501/parallel-axes-between-inertial-frames-in-special-relativity

Comment: @Frobenius: You're after MathJaX stuff? This is not on-topic here!

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer : Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot you've posted suggests you're interested in Times Roman-based Fonts. If that's the case, I suggest you load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. The latter package, happily, provides "upright" lowercase Greek math symbols. They may be accessed by prefixing "up" to the macro for the ordinary symbol (e.g., `\upalpha`, `\upbeta`, etc.).

To typeset the right-hand curly brace that's shown in your screenshot, you could encase the two equations in an `array` environment, as is done in the code shown below. Alternatively, you could load the `mathtools` package and use a `drcases` environment.

Aside: I wouldn't typeset the `\cdot` symbol in bold unless `\boldsymbol{\cdot}` really is supposed to differ meaningfully from `\cdot`. And, if you have a lot of instances of "`\boldsymbol{\upbeta}`", you may want to define a shortcut macro--say, `\newcommand\bupbeta{\boldsymbol{\upbeta}}`--to simplify the keyboarding of your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,array}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\left. \begin{array}{r @{{}={}} >{\displaystyle}l }
x'_0 & \gamma ( x_0^{} - \boldsymbol{\upbeta} \cdot \mathbf{x}) \\[1ex]
\mathbf{x}' & \mathbf{x}+\frac{(\gamma-1)}{\beta^2}
    (\boldsymbol{\upbeta} \cdot \mathbf{x})\boldsymbol{\upbeta}
    -\gamma\boldsymbol{\upbeta}x_0^{}
\end{array}\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but I realize that my question is off-topic here since it's about MathJax stuff, please see comments in Christian Hupfer's answer.

Comment: Although my question is off-topic, your answer is very valuable for me to use in documents  I edit for my own pleasure with LaTeX.

Comment: @Frobenius - Feel free to modify your posting so that MathJax is no longer an important aspect.